# Reverse relationship in join table

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord

I have a user friendship model that I want to write a lookup for

is a habtm relationship called peers, relating 2 users together. A relationship is a single connection (Joe <-> Steve, not Joe -> Steve and Steve -> Joe).

My join table is as follows:
user_id
peer_id

Both store a user id in the relationship. Below is the HABTM on the user.

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :peers, class_name: 'User', 
foreign_key: 'user_id', association_foreign_key: 'peer_id', 
join_table: 'users_peers'
```

I am trying to figure out the finder sql that will allow this record in the join table to show both sides.
user_id = steve.id
peer_id = joe.id

to show the relationships when I call joe.peers and steve.peers. Currently, steve.peers returns joe, but joe.peers shows nothing.

Comment: see related:  http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10199/how-should-i-design-a-relationship-table-for-friendship

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally relationships are best expressed as one way, or a pair of one-way relationships. This is because in most relational databases, it's easy to establish an A to B or B to A relationship, but not both with one record. You basically need two queries unless you make a lot of assumptions and hack around.

In my experience, using `has_and_belongs_to_many` isn't going to make your life easier as it's a relic from Rails 1.0 that isn't nearly as good as the `has_many :through` method that replaced it. In your case this is how that would play out:

```
class Node < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :peers_of,
    :class_name => 'Peer',
    :foreign_key => :of_user_id

  has_many :peers_to,
    :class_name => 'Peer',
    :foreign_key => :to_user_id

  has_many :peers,
    :through => :peers_of,
    :source => :to_user

  has_many :peers_with,
    :through => :peers_to,
    :source => :of_user
end

class Peer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :of_user,
    :class_name => 'User'
  belongs_to :to_user,
    :class_name => 'User'
end
```

The semantics get a little messy, so you'll probably want to adjust them. The idea here is to establish a bi-directional relationship when adding a "peer", where that consists of a pair of A->B and B->A records.

For the purposes of querying you would only fetch, for instance, `@user.peers` and not have to worry about the `peers_with` inverse relationship as that should produce identical results if you've maintained data integrity.

Comment: Thanks, I will give that a look. I was just hoping for some magic :) - Bi-directional self-referential relationships make my mind hurt a little...

Comment: It's easier to write a task to validate and repair the relationships if one of the pairs is missing than it is to figure out how to make a uni-directional relationship function as a bi-directional one.

Answer (score 1):

You could just write the sql by hand:

```
class PeerRelation
  belongs_to :user1, :class_name=>"User"
  belongs_to :user2, :class_name=>"User"
end

class User

  def set_peer(user)
     user1_id, user2_id = [self.id, user.id].sort
     PeerRelation.find_or_create_by_user1_id_and_user2_id(user1_id, user2_id)
  end

  def peers
    User.joins("inner join peer_relations on 
                  peer_relations.user1_id = #{self.id} or
                  peer_relations.user2_id = #{self.id}")

  end
end
```

But tadman's approach is smarter from a data-integrity perspective, and is more in line with what a DBA would tell you.  (see my comment to your question)

Comment: You could also implement that as a `finder_sql` definition on the relationship, but doing a `JOIN` with an `OR` in it makes most databases cry if the table is large.